# how to read audio file in fire fox using file reader class

Tags: javascript, audio, firefox-os

```
saveButton.onclick = function(e) {
   var filename= file.name;
   console.warn("file name " +filename);
 //alert("hello");
  var audioType = "audio/*";
  //console.warn("audiotype " +audioType);
      if(filename.type.match(audioType))
      {
      console.warn("audiotype " +audioType);
      var reader=new FileReader();
      console.warn("file reader object " +reader);
      read.onload=function(e)
     {
     var rowdata=reader.result;
     console.warn("file reader object row data " +rowdata);
     }
       reader.readAsBinaryString(filename);
    }
         }
```

here on save button event i am  getting audio file name using file.name.now i want to read it in buffer because i want to upload this  file on server.so i want to read it using file reader class.but here i am not getting any output.can any one plzz help me to figure out that where is the problem in this code.

Comment: you don't need a FileReader to upload it...

Comment: I dont knw how to upload this file i am working on fire fox os.but i have seen this as a one solution so i am applying it.if you have any other solution then plzz suggest it.

Comment: @user3679542 is it on firefox or firefoxos?

Answer (score 1):

Very broad solution, supposing you are using a POST request to upload your file and your server is accepting POST request.

```
var myFile;
var myForm = new FormData();
myform.append('nameOfThefile', myFile, 'nameOfTheFileWithExtension');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://foo.com/submitform.php');
xhr.send(myForm);
```

Brief explanation; you have a *file* object called *myFile* and want to upload it to a server, you need to make a request with XMLHttpRequest and append a formData field to it. The easier way to do that is using a *FormData* object, append your file to it and send the *FormData* with the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I guess the answer is fine. The question is quite broad though.